# What is the point of providing a JOIN condition when there are foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

**TL;DR**: Why do we have to add `ON table1.column = table2.column`?

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262554/database-design-whats-the-point-of-identifying-foreign-keys) asks roughly why do we need to have foreign keys if joining works just fine without them. Here, I'd like to ask the reverse. Given the simplest possible database, like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE class (
  class_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  class_name VARCHAR(40)
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE student (
  student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  student_name VARCHAR(40),
  class_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY(class_id) REFERENCES class(class_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

… and a simple join, like this:

```sql
SELECT student_id, student_name, class_name
FROM student
JOIN class
ON student.class_id = class.class_id;
```

… why can't we just omit the `ON` clause?

```sql
SELECT student_id, student_name, class_name
FROM student
JOIN class;
```

To me, the line `FOREIGN KEY(class_id) REFERENCES class(class_id) …` in the definition of `student` already includes all the necessary information for the `FROM student JOIN class` to have an implicit `ON student.class_id = class.class_id` condition; but we still have to add it. Why is that?

Comment: a)you don't *have* to join on FKs and b) sometimes multiple FKs exist between the same pair of tables. c) SQL is a crusty language without many shortcuts for the most common use case

Comment: Don't be lazy, specify the join conditions! (Which also means avoid NATURAL JOIN.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Reposting [Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) as an answer*</sup>

- you don't have to join on foreign keys;
- sometimes multiple foreign keys exist between the same pair of tables.

Also, SQL is a crusty language without many shortcuts for the most common use case.

Answer (score 0):

- For this you must consider the JOIN operation. It doesn't check if your two table or collection have relation or not. So the simple join without condition (ON) you will have a big result with all possibilities.
- The ON operation filters to get your expected result

Answer (score 0):

JOIN condition is an expression which specifies the maching criteria, and it is checked during JOIN process. It can cause a fail only if syntax error occures.

FOREIGN KEY is a rule for data consistency checking subsystem, and it is checked during data change. It will cause a fail if the data state (intermnediate and/or final) does not match the rule.

In other words, there is nothing in common between them, they are completely different and unrelated things.

---

> I feel like I have to reiterate parts of the question. Please, give it a second read - Dima Parzhitsky

Imagine that your offer is accepted. I have tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (userid INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE messages (sender INT REFERENCES users (userid), 
                       receiver INT REFERENCES users (userid));
```

I write `SELECT * FROM users JOIN messages`.

What reference must be used for joining condition? And justify your assumption...

Comment: A JOIN condition can fail for a number of other reasons too.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying they're the same thing; I'm saying that using foreign key information would help when joining

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Imagine that the joining logic of some particular query needs to use joining condition which differs from FK expression... PS. In MySQL JOIN without ON clause is allowed (this is an extension) and is an alias of CROSS JOIN.

Comment: I totally get that the implicit condition I'm asking about won't fit 100% of JOIN situations (SQL JOINs are notorious for how complex they can get); my question is more of a "why don't allow it in this particular very common and obvious case?". Your answer is definitely useful knowledge-wise, but Damien's comment (the first one) does a better job of answering this question.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Server won't understand special/particular situations - it needs in one rule which matches 100% of queries.

Comment: I feel like I have to reiterate parts of the question. Please, give it a second read, reach below the TLDR.

Comment: (In response to the update in the answer) The result could be an error, something like "ambiguous reference", — a similar error appears when SELECTing two identical keys from two tables without providing table identifiers